# Kops cluster creates more nodes than expected on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

I new to kubernetes and kobs and are starting to create a cluster using

```
kops create cluster --zones eu-central-1a,eu-central-1b  ${NAME}
```

After I have created I can see that the following

```
> kops get instancegroups --name=${NAME}
NAME                    ROLE    MACHINETYPE     MIN     MAX     ZONES
master-eu-central-1a    Master  t3.medium       1       1       eu-central-1a
nodes-eu-central-1a     Node    t3.medium       1       1       eu-central-1a
nodes-eu-central-1b     Node    t3.medium       1       1       eu-central-1b
```

Where I would expect the output to look more like this following the tutorial.

```
NAME                    ROLE    MACHINETYPE     MIN     MAX     ZONES
master-eu-central-1a    Master                  1       1       eu-central-1a
nodes                   Node    t2.medium       2       2
```

I can of course configure both the nodes in each subnet but it seems wrong. Am I on the wrong track?

Answer (score 1):

That is the expected node count. The cluster was created with `--zones eu-central-1a,eu-central-1b`. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/cli/kops_create_cluster.md) kops will create one node per zone:

> `--node-count` `int32`                 Set total number of nodes. Defaults to one node per zone

If kops should create only one node `--zones eu-central-1a` should be set or set `--node-count 1`. I guess this setting can be changed with [kops edit](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/cli/kops_edit.md) command.